# what's the best rendering filter to play videos on  THE KMPLAYER?

Tags: codec, kmplayer

I'm using  THE KMPLAYER to watch my videos.  I'm not familar with codecs or rendering filters .

I choosed `VMR9 Renderless (HQ subtitle )` by testing once after once. it seems good !

which one is the best ? can i add other rendering filters ? Is it important ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best codec to use is the one that your video/audio is encoded in.

[VMR-9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not a codec, it is a rendering filter used by DirectX 9.

To install video codecs, just download the codec or codec pack and run the setup program.

Comment: uhm, i edited the question, which rendering filter is good to use ? tnx

Answer (score 0):

first, just to be sure, do you mean [THE KMPLAYER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Multimedia_Player)? Because beside the Korean player there is also MPlayer based [KMPLAYER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konqueror_Media_Player).

About the codecs - the player should be able to choose appropriate codec for each video, so you should not try to force it to play Quicktime MOV video using Windows Media video codec as it would not work.

Which particular codecs do you miss in the Kmplayer? It already contains plenty of built in codecs so there is mostly no reason to install additional ones.

Comment: yes, I use THE KMPLAYER, question has edited